# Python: automatically add a check digit to a 4 digit number

Tags: python

I have a program that allows a user to input 10 names and store in a list using a for loop.  Inside the loop I have created a unique ID number which I want to add a check digit to the number  (method: by adding digits up, multiplying by their position 1-4) then using MOD 10)

How do I add the check digit to each unique number within a loop and store in the list.

Thanks for the help.

```
Staff =[] 
ID = [] 
Unique = 100 
Check = 0 
for i in range (0,3):
    Name = input("Enter your name:\n") 
    Staff.append (Name) 
    Unique = Unique + 1 
    p1 = (Unique[0]) 
    p2 = Unique [1] 
    p3 = Unique [2] 
    Check = ((p1*3)+(p2*2)+(p3*1))%10 
    Full = Unique,Check 
    ID.append (Full) 

for i in range (0,3): 
    print(Staff [i], ID [i]) 

#Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: can you post your code here so that we can see where/how to add the check digit?

Comment: Staff =[]
ID = []
Unique = 100 
Check = 0
for i in range (0,3):
    Name = input("Enter your name:\n")
    Staff.append (Name)
    Unique = Unique + 1
    p1 = (Unique[0])
    p2 = Unique [1]
    p3 = Unique [2]
    check = ((p1*3)+(p2*2)+(p3*1))%10
    Full = Unique,check
    ID.append (Full)

for i in range (0,3):
    print(Staff [i], ID [i])
    
#Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: can you please format your code? it's difficult to understand it as hot it is right now.

Comment: i meant how it is (not hot it is)

Comment: @Mrmac Just a suggestion: try to follow [PEP8 conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) on variable naming. For example, use `name` instead of `Name` (uppercase style like `Name` should be used instead for classes). It makes it clearer for cases like `Staff.append` to know if it's an instance method or a class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you use:

```
for i in range (0,3):
    Name = input("Enter your name:\n") 
    Staff.append (Name) 
    Unique = Unique + 1 
    strUnique = str(Unique)
    p1 = int(strUnique[0])
    p2 = int(strUnique[1]) 
    p3 = int(strUnique[2]) 
    Check = ((p1*3)+(p2*2)+(p3*1))%10 
    Full = Unique,Check 
    ID.append (Full)
```

`int` object is not subscriptable, `str` object is.

You can also make it more pythonic:

```
for i in range (0,3):
    Name = input("Enter your name:\n") 
    Staff.append (Name) 
    Unique = Unique + 1 
    p1,p2,p3 = map(int,str(Unique))
    Check = ((p1*3)+(p2*2)+(p3*1))%10 
    Full = Unique,Check 
    ID.append (Full)
```

or just do it in a single line:

```
for i in range (0,3):
    Name = input("Enter your name:\n") 
    Staff.append (Name) 
    Unique = Unique + 1 
    Check = sum(map(lambda t:t[0]*t[1],enumerate(map(int,str(unique)[::-1]),1)))%10
    Full = Unique,Check 
    ID.append (Full)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:   I am still getting an error message:  Check = ((p1*3)+(p2*2)+(p3*1))%10  TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @Mr mac I'm sorry, my fault, I'll soon edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am new to programming and really appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you.  That works perfectly.  Also thanks for the other more efficient ideas.  Have a great weekend.

Comment: @Mrmac If this answer helped you, you can upvote it and/or mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).